# Prevent global variables from being cleared

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables, global

If I have a global variable in VBA and I assign a value to it on Workbook.open(), is there a way to preserve this assigned value, even if the "Reset" button is clicked in the code (or the code is ended due to a bug)?

Example:

```
Public myGlobalVariable As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  'Ask the user for the value of the global variable
  myGlobalVariable = InputBox("Give me some input", "Hi", 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, why not use `Environ("Username")` directly instead of using a variable?

Comment: Fair point, it might not have been the best example. I need it for other varibles as well. And while I might be able to find a workaround in all cases, it would be a lot easier if there was a way to prevent global variables from being killed. I've changed it to a different example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to persist them somewhere - eg a cell, defined name, registry, file.

Comment: Thank you, even though it was not the answer I had hoped for.